# marginal distribution in context to tranfer learning

Tags: machine-learning, transfer-learning

In transfer learning, we often come across marginal distributions in the target and source domain as being different. In simple terms, what does it essentially mean?

I have read about marginal distributions, how is it calculated etc. but still the notion of marginal distribution as applied in transfer learning is not quite clear to me.

Any idea?

Do let me know what predictive distribution means in the same context and how to differentiate between the two.